# convert Java datestring to javascript date

Tags: javascript, string, json, date

When I send a date through JSON from Java to Javascript, it sends something like this:

```
var ds = "11:07:47 13/01/2011";
```

Javascript fails to parse this string into date

```
var d = new Date(ds);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Tthis was asked on January 2011, dup link is April 2011, how can this be a duplicate ?

Comment: The “duplicate” is closed for being unclear what is asked. Time to reopen this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need some JS that parse the String and return the year, month, day, minute,hour, second in strings:

```
var hour = ds.split(":")[0],
    minute = ds.split(":")[1],
    last_part = ds.split(":")[2],
    second = second_part.split(" ")[0],
    last_part2 = second_part.split(" ")[1],
    day = last_part2.split("/")[0],
    month =  last_part2.split("/")[1],
    year =  last_part2.split("/")[2];
```

and then instantiate the Date constructor:

```
var d = new Date ( year, month, day, hour, minute, second );
```

Comment: Line 3 should be `second = ds.split(":")[2],`, delete 4th line, 5th line should be `last_part2 = ds.split(" ")[1],`. You could rename last_part2 as it isn't the 2nd one anymore.

Comment: thanks for writing the code , it worked like a charm!

Comment: An alternate approach would be to use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com) to get a `Date` object: `var d = moment(ds, "HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY").asDate();` The second string is the format to use for parsing the input date String.

Answer (score 5):

To be on the safe side you should get the time in milliseconds in Java and send that through JSON to JavaScript. There you can use

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(valueInMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways you can call the `Date` constructor.
From the reference at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function stringToDate(_date,_format,_delimiter)
{
        var formatLowerCase=_format.toLowerCase();
        var formatItems=formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
        var dateItems=_date.split(_delimiter);
        var monthIndex=formatItems.indexOf("mm");
        var dayIndex=formatItems.indexOf("dd");
        var yearIndex=formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
        var month=parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
        month-=1;
        var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex],month,dateItems[dayIndex]);
        return formatedDate;
}

stringToDate("17/9/2014","dd/MM/yyyy","/");
stringToDate("9/17/2014","mm/dd/yyyy","/")
stringToDate("9-17-2014","mm-dd-yyyy","-")
```