# How to convert date from European format

Tags: angular

**THE SITUATION**:

From the API i get the dates in the european format: `01-06-2018` 
  That is: day - month - year (1 june 2018).

I need to display in a more beautiful way - the ['d MMM y'](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) format is exactly what I need.

But if i use the pipeline in the view in this way:

```
{{ projectInfo.project_start_date | date: 'd MMM y' }}
```

The result is: `6 Jan 2018` (while in my case should be `1 Jun 2018`)

Because it thinks that the first two cyphers of my date `01-06-2018` are the month - while they are days..

**THE QUESTION**:

How can convert European formatted dates in Angular 2?

Should I convert them in the component from European format to American format?

If yes - do you know how that can be done in Angular 2?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

This how I have tried to convert the string i received from the API into an actual date:

In the component:

```
dateTest: Date;
this.dateTest = new Date(this.projectInfo['project_start_date']);
```

In the view:

```
<span> {{ dateTest | date: 'd MMM y' }} </span>
```

The result:

Still the same: 6 Jan 2018

**PLUNKER**:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZYMoaoxawVCtScUZfL3B?p=preview

Comment: I think the problem stays in the projectInfo.project_start_date. Is it a string or a Javascript Date?

Comment: Because if it is a string, Angular would try to automatically convert it to a date and then format it. The problem is that Angular interprets the date in American format, that's where's the problem. In that case you would need to convert the strings into dates BEFORE processing them.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to resort to a method like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4679696/2947592

Comment: or `var pattern = /(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/;         
        var dt = new Date(dateString.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1'));` which works for european dates (euro dates only tho)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have edited the question. The string is converted into a actual date - but is of course an american date.

Comment: `isoDate = europeDate.split("-").reverse().join("-");` - from there you should be able to pass it in unambiguously.

Comment: You're coing to need https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: @Rob Hey dude. Could you please reconsider removing the duplicate. Since this is a specific question regarding the european date format and in the context of Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

All pipes seem to rely on the locale. Try to change it from your main module :

```
providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" }, //replace "en-US" with your locale
     appRoutingProviders 
]
```

[sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular2/39344889#39344889)